# What is $\max\langle x,Ax\rangle$ over subspaces non-invariant under $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Let $A$ be an Hermitian matrix in a vector space $V$, and let $U\le V$ be a subspace of $V$.

If $U$ is invariant under $A$, then the maximum of $\langle x,Ax\rangle$ over all unit vectors $x\in U$ equals the largest eigenvalue of $A$ whose eigenvector is in $U$ (and we know $U$ is spanned by eigenvectors of $A$, as otherwise it wouldn't be invariant under its action).
Similar ideas are used for example to prove the [min-max principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

What about subspaces $U$ that are *not* invariant under $A$? More precisely, is there a way to find
$$\max_{x\in U}\frac{\langle x,Ax\rangle}{\|x\|^2}$$
for arbitrary subspaces $U$?
Of course, feel free to remove the Hermitianity constraint if the problem is better posed in a more general setting.

Decomposing an arbitrary $x\in U$ as $x=\sum_k c_k x_k=\sum_j d_j u_j$ where $x_k$ are a basis of eigenvectors of $A$ and $u_k$ an orthonormal basis for $U$, we have
$$\langle x,Ax\rangle = \sum_k \lambda_k |c_k|^2,$$
but the problem is that the maximisation is constrained to those coefficients $(c_k)$ such that $\sum_k c_k x_k\in U$,

Comment: If $P$ is the projector onto the subspace $U$ then for all $ x\in U$ we have $\langle x, Ax\rangle  = \langle P x, A P x \rangle = \langle x, PAP x\rangle$. Then $PAP$ Is a Hermitian matrix which leaves the subspace $U$ invariant and so we can solve it using the same method presented in the question. Would such a method be sufficient?

Comment: @Rammus , you may be waiting for someone to copy your comment and write it as an answer.

Comment: @Rammus that sounds like a good approach. Maybe complemented by an observation about the relation between the largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $PAP$

Comment: @glS I'm not sure if I know of any relation that is not just trivial, i.e., $\|PAP\| \leq \|P\|\|A\|\|P\| = \|A\|$. This can be equality if the eigenvector corresponding to the largest absolute eigenvalue is contained within $U$. I'll update my answer if I think of something though.

Comment: @Rammus that's probably the best one can do using no more information than the eigenvalues of $A$. So we observe that maximising $\langle x,Ax\rangle$ for $x\in U$ is equivalent to unconstrained maximisation of $\langle x,PAPx\rangle$ with $P$ projecting onto $U$. But $PAP$ is also Hermitian thus this maximum equals its max eigenvalue, which can be bounded by that of $A$. Sounds good. If you write an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @glS It's not quite equivalent to the unconstrained maximization of $PAP$. To see this imagine $P$ projects onto the eigenspace of the strictly negative eigenvalues of $A$ (assuming it has some). Then, maximizing over U would give something strictly negative whereas maximizing over $V$ would give $0$. If you add an absolute value around the inner product then these two optimizations would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let P be the projector onto the subspace $U$. Then for all $x \in U$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle x, A x \rangle &= \langle P x, A P x \rangle \\
&= \langle x, PAP x\rangle. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, we have 
$$
\max_{x\in U}\frac{\langle x,Ax\rangle}{\|x\|^2} = \max_{x\in U}\frac{\langle x,PAPx\rangle}{\|x\|^2}. 
$$
Now $PAP$ is an operator that leaves the subspace $U$ invariant and so as noted in the question the maximum is given by the largest eigenvalue of $PAP$ whose eigenvector is in $U$. Note that we have an upper bound of $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ (largest eigenvalue of A) which can be seen be noticing the original problem is upper bounded by the same problem but with a maximization over the whole space $V$.